# Getting at runtime class information when you cannot specify ClassTag

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

When writing tests to verify that the proper typeclass is selected somewhere in the internals, I've run into *type erasure*. I don't have the option of adding `ClassTag` to the signature, unless I also pollute the non-test version of the trait because adding `: ClassTag` changes the method signature so that it's no longer an override, e.g.:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar[T: MyTypeClass](t: T): Unit
}

class FooStubImpl extends Foo {
  override def bar[T: MyTypeClass: ClassTag](t: T): Unit = {
    val ct = classTag[T]
  }
}
```

This causes the following compilation error:

> Error:(12, 20) method bar overrides nothing
>       Note: the super classes of class FooStubImpl contain the following, non final member named bar:
>
> ```
> override def bar[T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: MyTypeClass[T]): Unit = {
>          ^
> ```

Is there another way of getting at runtime type information of parametrized types that doesn't require `ClassTag`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to test whether or not the right type class was selected by a simple equality check? I'd like to see a use-case where the test is broken by erasure.

Comment: BTW, you forgot `extends Foo`, although it doesn't change the compiler error in this case.

Comment: @m-z actually you are correct, in the case of typeclasses this wasn't a problem since those are implicit objects that i can do equality tests on. I ran into the problem once i couldn't use a typeclass because it was taking custom arguments and was instantiating different parameterized classes in a case statement. I'll try to extract an example in a code snippet that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *runtime value* of the type at question, simply check that type. Class-tags are only needed if you have no value evidence.

```
class FooStubImpl extends Foo {
  override def bar[T: MyTypeClass](t: T): Unit = {
    val clazz = t.getClass
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks. Going back to my test code to figure out what i had different that it complaint that my equality test was useless due to type erasure. I must have missed something in translation